# Bootstrap 5 - Option Select change background color and font color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the background color and the font color of the option inside the form select element. I've used Boostrap 5.

I would like when I have clicked shows the options with a custom background color and font color:

form select options
[image]

The html code:

```css
select option {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected id="Subject">Subject</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/) the official documentation.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really possible and nothing to do with Bootstrap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css

Answer (score 2):

I Don't know if I understanded you but try this..

```
select option:checked {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: white!important;
}
```

It will set a custom colors for selected item if that what u want.